# How does one convert a data set with two labels +1 and -1 to a hot one vector representation in a vectorized way in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, vector

I have a data set in numpy with a x vector and a y vector. The y vectors is only two values +1 or -1 (or 0 or 1) because its a binary valued function. I know I can just loop over the data set and if I see a +1 to map it to 1 and if I see and -1 map it to 0 one by one. However, I was hoping that given the whole vector `y = [N x 1]` to map it in one step to a vector `y = [N x 2]` since can be quite large I wanted to do it as quickly as possible (I also didn't want to save the copy of the data set twice).

Is there a vectorized way to do this transformation quickly in python?

---

For the reference here is the looping code:

```
def transform_data_to_one_hot(X,Y):
    N,D = Y.size
    Y_new = np.zeros(N,D)
    for i in range(N):
        if y == -1:
            Y_new[i] = np.array([1,0])
        else:
            Y_new[i] = np.array([0,1])
    return Y_new
```

---

Lets do the parity function using Radamacher variables (i.e. +1,-1 instead of 0 and 1). In this case the parity function is just the product function:

```
>>> X = np.array([[-1,-1],[-1,1],[1,-1],[1,1]])
>>> X
array([[-1, -1],
       [-1,  1],
       [ 1, -1],
       [ 1,  1]])

>>> Y = np.reshape(np.prod(X,axis=1),[4,1])
>>> Y
array([[ 1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [ 1]])
```

the Y vector when is one hot should be:

```
>>> Y
array([[ 0,1],
       [1,0],
       [1,0],
       [ 0,1]])
```

Comment: are you after `a[a == -1] = 0` ? (where `a` is your array...)

Comment: @MaxU I guess I am! but u mean `a[a == -1] = np.array([1,0])`

Comment: can you provide a small reproducible input data set and a desired data set?

Comment: @MaxU yes. give me one sec

Comment: @MaxU for the reference, the one hot encoding means each element in the array encodes for a class label. So in this case there are two labels `+1` and `-1`. So the encoding of `-1` can be `[1,0]` and for `+1` `[0,1]`

Comment: i tried to use your fuction in order to understand how your desired data set should look like, but your function doesn't work for me... Can you post also the desired data set?

Comment: @MaxU yea I just realized it doesn't work...I need to debug it....sorry about that. Let me see whats wrong :/

Comment: @MaxU seems that Divakar's answer is what I want...essentially (conceptually) the same as what you suggested. Thanks Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one initialization based -

```
def initialization_based(y):
    out = np.zeros((len(y),2),dtype=int)
    out[np.arange(out.shape[0]), (y==1).astype(int)] = 1
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [244]: y
Out[244]: array([ 1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1])

In [245]: initialization_based(y)
Out[245]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

Other ways to use `initialization` method -

```
def initialization_based_v2(y):
    out = np.zeros((len(y),2),dtype=int)
    out[np.arange(out.shape[0]), (y+1)//2] = 1
    return out

def initialization_based_v3(y):
    yc = y.copy()
    yc[yc==-1] = 0
    out = np.zeros((len(y),2),dtype=int)
    out[np.arange(out.shape[0]), yc] = 1
    return out
```

The two new additions only differ in the way we are setting up the column indices. For version 2, we have those computed with simply  : `(y+1)//2`, while for the version `3` as : `yc = y.copy(); yc[yc==-1] = 0`.

Another one that gets pretty close to [`@Eric's one`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43826322/3293881), but uses boolean array -

```
def initialization_based_v4(y):
    out = np.empty((len(y),2),dtype=int)
    mask = y == 1    
    out[:,0] = mask
    out[:,1] = ~mask
    return out
```

---

Runtime test -

```
In [320]: y = 2*np.random.randint(0,2,(1000000))-1

In [321]: %timeit sign_to_one_hot(y, dtype=int)
     ...: %timeit initialization_based(y)
     ...: %timeit initialization_based_v2(y)
     ...: %timeit initialization_based_v3(y)
     ...: %timeit initialization_based_v4(y)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.16 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 8.39 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 27.2 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 13.8 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.11 ms per loop

In [322]: from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

In [323]: enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)

In [324]: %timeit enc.fit_transform(np.where(y>=0, y, 0))
10 loops, best of 3: 77.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: whats the difference with ur answer and eric's?

Comment: also can u comment how ur different versions are different?

Comment: are you sure the first one is correct? the unit test I wrote has it that it always returns the matrix with all 1's.

Comment: @Pinocchio By first one, do you mean `initialization_based`?

Comment: yes the one without v name. also the maskl one has a broadcasting error.

Comment: @Pinocchio Ah you are using a `2D` version of `y`. So, we need to feed in `initialization_based(y[:,0])`, similarly use `y[:,0]` instead of `y` for the other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

A few simple observations to making this efficient:

- Preallocate the result, rather than using `concatenate`
- `empty` is faster than `zeros` if you're just going to overwrite those zeros
- Use the `out` argument, to avoid temporaries

```
def sign_to_one_hot(x, dtype=np.float64):
    out = np.empty(x.shape + (2,), dtype=dtype)
    plus_one = out[...,0]
    minus_one = out[...,1]
    np.equal(x, 1, out=plus_one)
    np.subtract(1, plus_one, out=minus_one)
    return out
```

Choose your dtype carefully - casting because you chose the wrong one will incur a copy

Comment: whats the difference with Divakar's answer?

Comment: @Pinocchio: This answer allocates no extra memory, whereas the others do

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) method.

NOTE: it doesn't accept negative numbers, so we have to replace them.

Demo:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# per default it generates sparsed matrix - it might be very useful for huge data sets    
enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)

rslt =  enc.fit_transform(np.where(Y>=0, Y, 0))
```

Result:

```
In [140]: rslt
Out[140]:
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
```

Source array:

```
In [141]: Y
Out[141]:
array([[ 1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [ 1]])
```

---

Pandas solution:

```
In [148]: pd.get_dummies(Y.ravel())
Out[148]:
   -1   1
0   0   1
1   1   0
2   1   0
3   0   1
```